# How to form a tuple of numpy array from a directory of Images or a csv file?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, data-preprocessing

I working on a project regarding Convolutional Neural Networks but I am quite new to using Python. The usage of different libraries has overwhelmed me.

I stored different training images in the same directory and also created a csv file with dataset and labels. After using the ImageDataGenerator to create variant of images, the data would be fed the flow from data frame for further processing instead of the flow_from_director, as there are more than two labels to match the images. I realized I must use fit() function to calculate the mean and std among the images, then the flow_from_data_frame would use the value calculated for doing normalization and zero mean operation with the images.

My questions are:

1. how to form a tuple of numpy array from a directory of Images or a csv file, just like the 'x_train' from tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()?
2. I also not quite sure how to feed fit() as an input of flow_from_data_frame, as I added .png on the ID of my csv file.

p.s. If you think my plan would not work, please point it out. I would much appreciate it. Thank you.

Below are my code,directory and csv file:
Code1:

```
def append_ext(fn):
return fn+".png"
traindf=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python\COVID-19/COVID- 
19RadiographyDataLabel.csv',dtype=str)
traindf["ID"]=traindf["ID"].apply(append_ext)
testdf=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python\COVID- 
19/SampleDataLabel.csv',dtype=str)
testdf["ID"]=testdf["ID"].apply(append_ext)
```

Code2:

```
datagen=ImageDataGenerator(featurewise_center = True,
                       featurewise_std_normalization = True,
                       rescale=1./255.,
                       rotation_range=10, 
                       width_shift_range=0.2, 
                       height_shift_range=0.2, 
                       zoom_range=0.2, 
                       horizontal_flip=True, 
                       brightness_range=[0.2,1.2],
                       validation_split=0.25,
                       preprocessing_function=Gray_to_Color
```

Code3:

```
train_iterator = datagen.fit(traindf)
```

[Directory: Total Number of Training Images:20165](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BR18m.png)

[Training csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiIIz.png)

[Code1output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MTMd.png)

[Code_cifar10.load_Data()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VLDk.png)

[Code3outputError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCdL9.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors; see [ask].

Comment: I am sorry. I edited it.

Comment: @TSLee Your dataframe does not consist of images, and adding .png will not convert the ID's to images. Did you try using `image_dataset_from_directory` ?

Comment: @Tfer3 No, as image_dataset_from_directory is only suitable when using 2 labels

Comment: @TSLee From [here](https://tensorflow.google.cn/tutorials/load_data/images?hl=en), you can see that image_dataset_from_directory can be used when there are more than two labels. Thanks!